# How to add dependecies in a bash file?

Tags: java, bash

I'm working on a java project and I have 3 projects :

```
-banking
-logger
-testframework
```

banking is used to manage accounts,
logger is used in banking to log users actions and
testframework is for tests

I am working on a compile.sh and a launch_banking.sh and this is my problem :
when I launch launch_banking.sh, I get these errors :

```
firefrost@firefrost-PC:~/ProjetPOO3A$ bash launch_banking.sh 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: logger/LoggerFactory
    at banking.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logger.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
firefrost@firefrost-PC:~/ProjetPOO3A$
```

this is the content of launch_banking.sh :

```
java -classpath banking/bin banking.Launcher;
```

this is how I compile my project (compile.sh):

```
javac -d logger/bin $(find logger/src -name *.java);
javac -classpath logger/bin -d banking/bin $(find banking/src -name *.java);
```

I am working under Ubuntu and I use eclipse to code my projetc.
I am forced to use batch files to compile and launch my projetc.

I've done some research and it seems I need to use dependencies but I don't know what they are.

This is the structure of the project :

```
+--_logger
| +-- _src
| | +-- _logger
| | +-- (.java)
| +-- _bin
+-- _testframework
| +-- _src
| | +-- _test
| | +-- (.java)
| +-- _bin
+-- _banking
| +-- _src
| | +-- _banking
| | +-- (*.java)
| +-- _bin
+-- compile.sh
+-- test.sh
+-- launch_banking.sh
+-- README.md
```

Comment: "Forced to use batch files"?  Just to make sure we're on the same page, you're aware that tools like Maven and Gradle are specifically designed to handle this problem?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The teacher asked us to use batch files and no other tools. Basically, on any ubuntu computer, you just need to do a bash launch_banking.sh to lauch the program in the console.

Comment: Ok, but that will make life mind-bendingly painful for you :/  (And it strongly implies that your teacher ought not to be teaching this class...)  The problem seems to be that you're only putting the dependencies on the classpath for compilation, and not for runtime.

Comment: Independent of the build tooling : the class paths you use to compile with javac needs to match what you use when running your classes using java. In that sense : go and do some research on that classpath topic. And yes, using scripts to build and run Java stuff reads like your instructions are from the last century.

Comment: Seeing as these requirements are so archaic I wonder if the teacher requires you to have different packages/projects, if not you could have all the Java files in the same directory and then `javac *.java` might be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use classes that are in another directory, you need to define these in classpath as :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin banking.Launcher
```

this will tell the program to search in the logger AND banking directory for the classes